# Visual Basic 2010 Express Error: No Editor Available

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

When I open my SLN file in Visual Studio, it launches and loads correctly with no errors. When I select a VB file from the Solution Explorer, I get the following message:

[image: Error Message]

I have tried to associate the file type with Windows, but it is already associated. What can I do to get my files to open? HELP PLEASE!

**EDIT**
: I can right click and open any file in Visual Basic Express and it works, but the problem is that when I am in the IDE I cannot open files from the solution explorer which means I cannot edit the UI.

Comment: Right-click on the file and select "Open With..." What is selected?

Comment: @Cody Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010, and it asks if I want to keep using this

Comment: The VS installation did not go well.  If you had the VS11 preview edition installed then be sure to uninstall it first.  This kind of problem is otherwise caused by trouble with the registry.  You'll need to get your machine stable again.  Find help with that at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described was occurring due to a bug in the Windows 8 developer preview. Upgrading to the Consumer Edition fixes the problem, and adds a number of stability improvements, plus a  new Visual Studio IDE is available: Visual Studio 11.